# Replacing Inner for loop with Java Stream

Tags: java-8

I am learning Java Streams and want to replace the below code with java 8 features.

i was able to use stream.filter() and stream.map features , but i could not replace the below code with java 8 features.

```
List<Subject> subjects= null;
Set<SubjectData> subjectData= new SubjectData();
for (String name: studentNames)
{
    //subjects = student.getSubjects(name);
    // consider instead of above line , which returns a collection of <Subject>
    for (Subject subject : subjects)
    {
        subjectData.add(new SubjectData(subject.syllabus(), subject.code()));
    }
}
```

any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: Certainly, you mean `new HashSet<>()`?

Comment: Where does `student` come from?

Comment: yes the output of this code should return a collection of <SubjectData> for all the students (present in outer for loop)

Comment: student is a classlevel object

Comment: `Set<SubjectData> subjectData= new SubjectData();` - We cannot help you convert code that doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine something like this is what you intend:

```
Set<SubjectData> subjectData = studentNames.stream()
        .flatMap(name -> student.getSubjects(name).stream())
        .map(subject -> new SubjectData(subject.syllabus(), subject.code()))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

This streams the student names, maps them to their subjects while concatenating those streams, and then creates `SubjectData` objects for each. Lastly, those objects are collected into a set.